# Lifting the state from child to parent with React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, destructuring

I want to capture the data in my UserInput component and bring it back to the App.jsx and store it in the state.

My investment object looks like

```
const [initialInvestment, setInitialInvestment] = useState({
        initialInvestment: 100,
        annualInvestment: 200,
        expectedReturn: 3.3,
        duration: 4
    });
```

The object looks like

```
{
    initialInvestment: 100,
    annualInvestment: 200,
    expectedReturn: 3.3,
    duration: 4
}
```

My JSX code for the component UserInput.jsx

```
    <div id={'user-input'}>
        <div className={'input-group'}>
            <div>
                <label>Initial Investment</label>
                <input type={'number'} defaultValue={investment.initialInvestment} onKeyDown={event => onInvestmentUpdate(event)} required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Annual Investment</label>
                <input type={'number'} defaultValue={investment.annualInvestment} onKeyDown={event => onInvestmentUpdate(event)} required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Expected Return</label>
                <input type={'number'} defaultValue={investment.expectedReturn} onKeyDown={event => onInvestmentUpdate(event)} required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Duration</label>
                <input type={'number'} defaultValue={investment.duration} onKeyDown={event => onInvestmentUpdate(event)} required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to lift the state from the UserInput and bring it to App.jsx

App.jsx

```
const investmentHandler = (investment) => {
    //const newInvestment = [...initialInvestment, ...investment];
    setInitialInvestment(prevInvestment => {
        return {
            ...prevInvestment,
            investment
        }
    });
}

        <UserInput init={initialInvestment} onUpdate={investmentHandler}/>
```

Comment: @isherwood  I think I'm only saying all this, because I wish somebody had told me at the start :(,  I wish the DOC's instead of explaining HOC's, advised me to use a 3rd party state manager.  React currently has a big problem of keeping new users to React, and instead moving to Vue etc, and it's just this simply thing that's doing it.  React dev's even know this, the reason they made Recoil, although I think Jotai did a better job.  A popular survey found that most developers using React do it because they have too, were most devs using Vue/Angular use it because want too.  That's not right!!

Comment: @Keith, you're over my head, but I appreciate the info. I mostly use React for personal projects and not enterprise stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserInput.jsx

```
    <section id={'user-input'}>
        <div className={'input-group'}>
            <p>
                <label>Initial Investment</label>
                <input type={'number'} name={'initialInvestment'} value={investment.initialInvestment} onChange={event => onUpdate('initialInvestment', event.target.value)} required/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Annual Investment</label>
                <input type={'number'} name={'annualInvestment'} value={investment.annualInvestment} onChange={event => onUpdate('annualInvestment', event.target.value)} required/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Expected Return</label>
                <input type={'number'} name={'expectedReturn'} value={investment.expectedReturn} onChange={event => onUpdate('expectedReturn', event.target.value)} step={'0.1'} required/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Duration</label>
                <input type={'number'} name={'duration'} value={investment.duration} onChange={event => onUpdate('duration', event.target.value)} required/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

App.jsx

```
const handleChange = (inputIdentifier, newValue) => {
    setUserInput(previousUserInput => {
        return {
            ...previousUserInput,
            [inputIdentifier]: newValue
        };
    });
}

<UserInput investment={userInput} onUpdate={handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are fundamental data down/events up principles applied to your app as I understand it. I haven't worked through all the details, but it gives you an idea how it should look.

One thing I'm not clear on is why you only have an event handler for one input, yet you seem to want to update the entire object in the app's handler. I'd update object properties individually from specific form values, or just wait for the entire form to be submitted and do it all then.

```
// App.jsx
const App = () => {

    const [initialInvestment, setInitialInvestment] = useState({
        initialInvestment: 100,
        annualInvestment: 200,
        expectedReturn: 3.3,
        duration: 4
    });

    const onInvestmentChange = investment => {
        setInitialInvestment(prevInvestment => {
            return {
                ...prevInvestment,
                investment
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <UserInput investment={initialInvestment} onUpdate={onInvestmentChange}/>
    );
}

// UserInput.jsx
const UserInput = props => {
    const onInitialInvestmentChange = event => {
        const newData = [... props.investment];

        newData.initialInvestment = event.currentTarget.value;

        props.onUpdate(newData);
    }
    
    // other similar functions for each input
    const onAnnualInvestmentChange = event => {}
    const onExpectedReturnChange = event => {}
    const onDurationChange = event => {}

    return (
        <div id={'user-input'}>
            <div className={'input-group'}>
                <div>
                    <label>Initial Investment</label>
                    <input type={'number'} value={investment.initialInvestment}
                           onKeyDown={event => onInitialInvestmentChange(event)}
                           required/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Annual Investment</label>
                    <input type={'number'} value={investment.annualInvestment}
                            onKeyDown={event => onAnnualInvestmentChange (event)}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Expected Return</label>
                    <input type={'number'} value={investment.expectedReturn}
                            onKeyDown={event => onExpectedReturnChange (event)}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Duration</label>
                    <input type={'number'} value={investment.duration}
                            onKeyDown={event => onDurationChange (event)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: If I update all my input to use the same onInitialInvestmentChange. How will React know which input field is mapped to the investment object

Comment: You won't. See `// other similar functions for each input
`.